# How do I put the if function inside the lookup? - Daily Routine sheet

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, google-sheets-timestamp, microsoft-excel, time-tracker

I have a sheet - daily routine which has two columns: activity and time as shown here

| Activity | Time |
| --- | --- |
| Sleep | 6:00 am |
| Toilet | 6:15 am |
| Get ready for gym ‍♂️ | 6:30 am |
| Exercise | 7:50 am |
| ... more things | 9:00 pm |
| ... still more | 10:45 pm |
| Sleep | 6:00 am |

Here, say my toilet time would be from 6:00am to 6:15am
I want to find out, say in C1 which activity is current for me using now()
I.e., if it’s 6:45am on my watch, it should show me Exercise  in C1

Using the if function for time comparison and a lookup should solve my requirement, right?
Please help. How do I put the if function inside the lookup?

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. Thank you very much for including your data, and for **including it as text**. This makes the work of volunteers so much easier

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Index and Filter

(**Filter ()** creates a list of upcoming tasks, **Index ()** takes only the first of those)

```
=index(Filter(A2:A,timevalue(B2:B )>=timevalue(now())),1,1)
```

to get something like this:

[image: try]